# Express a hyperboloid

Tags: calculus

I have tried to find the parametric expressions of the following:
x^2+y^2-z^2=1 but I found difficulty.
If I use z=t, then how to express x and y?
Through polar coordinates?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you actually tried using polar coordinates as you suggest? What did you come up with? What specifically are you having trouble with? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/265466).

Comment: I came up with the equation that x^2+y^2=1+t^2 that represents a circle with (0,0) as center and radius r=sqrt(1+t^2). And so x=r*cosu and y=r*sinu, 0<=u<=2pi. Is that right or am I mistaken? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You should put that information in your question in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one parametrization of it:

$$x=\cosh \tau \cos \theta$$

$$y=\cosh \tau \sin \theta$$

$$z=\sinh \tau,$$

where $\tau\in\mathbb R, \theta\in[0,2\pi).$

Of course, the parametrization you gave, $(x,y,z)=(\sqrt{1+t^2}\cos \theta,\sqrt{1+t^2}\sin\theta,t),$ where $\theta\in[0,2\pi),t\in\mathbb R$ is also a valid parametrization.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible parameterizations of this surface. The choice of which one to use ultimately depends on what you’re planning to do with it.

Since this hyperboloid is the surface of revolution of a rectangular hyperbola in the $y$-$z$ plane about the $z$-axis, it seems natural to work in cylindrical coordinates. Choose your favorite parameterization of the hyperbola $r^2-z^2=1$ and then convert to Cartesian coordinates $x$ and $y$ by multiplying the expression for $r$ by $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$, respectively. Some common parameterizations of a hyperbola can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Parametric_equations), in the Wikipedia article on hyperbolas. I would opt for one in which the sign choice selects the branch of the hyperbola rather than its upper or lower half.

This is a ruled surface, however, so there’s another interesting way to parameterize it. This surface can be generated by rotating a particular line about the $z$-axis, so one can parameterize this line and then apply a rotation. There are many choices for the line, such as $(1,0,0)+t(0,-1,1)$. Rotating this through an angle of $\theta$ about the $z$-axis produces the parameterization $$x = \cos\theta+t\sin\theta \\ y = \sin\theta-t\cos\theta \\ z = t \\ t\in\mathbb R, 0\le\theta\lt2\pi.$$ Another interesting parameterization that uses the ruling is described in general form [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface#Examples). Basically, instead of rotating a line about the $z$-axis, you take a point on each of two circles centered on the $z$-axis and draw a line through them. A possible parameterization of this surface using that construction is $$(x,y,z) = (1-v)\left(\sqrt2\cos\left(u-\frac\pi4\right),\sqrt2\sin\left(u-\frac\pi4\right),1\right)+v\left(\sqrt2\cos\left(u+\frac\pi4\right),\sqrt2\sin\left(u+\frac\pi4\right),-1\right).$$ Note that after simplifying and setting $t = 1-2v$, this is not entirely surprisingly the same parameterization as that obtained by rotating a line that lies on the surface.

Comment: Thank you very much.